# perl $ anchor failed to match end of line

Tags: regex, perl

Example: `my $pattern = "mkdir a &"`

As you can see, my patterns are commands and I want to do a pattern match for "&+EOL" to distinguish whether this command runs on background or not.

I tried with `/&$/`, `/&\$/` but failed.

What is wrong? What is your suggestion with this pattern match?

`45:             if ($command =~ /&$/) {`

`DB<2> p $command`

`mkdir a &`

`DB<3> s`

`54:             print $_;print "\n";`

Comment: `/&$/` works - https://ideone.com/hOBnUu

Comment: Why can't mine? `45:             if ($command =~ /&$/) {`
  `DB<2> p $command`
`mkdir a &`
  `DB<3> s`
`54:             print $_;print "\n";`

Comment: Actually, no idea what you have after `&`. Maybe there are unprintable characters. See below answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pattern works fine

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $pattern = 'mkdir a &';

say $pattern =~ /&$/ ? 'match' : 'no match';
```

#### output

```
match
```

It is impossible to tell from your question, but it is likely that you have some whitespace at the end of the string you are trying to match. Perhaps you have a space or a linefeed there, or perhaps you are processing a file that has originated on Windows and you have removed only the LF, leaving a terminating CR.

You can fix this by adding optional whitespace at the end of your regex pattern, like this

```
say $pattern =~ /&\s*$/ ? 'match' : 'no match';
```

You can see exactly what your string contains using `Data::Dumper`, like this

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;

print Dumper $pattern;
```

In this instance it produces `$VAR1 = "mkdir a &";`, and you will be able to see if there are any superfluous characters after the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this : `/&\n|&$/`.

`$` match the end of the string so if yours commands are all in the same string the pattern will not work.

`\n` match a newline.

Comment: That's right: `\n` matches a newline. What if there is no newline, but the end of the string? Then, the pattern won't work. OP needs a *pattern match for "&+EOL"*, not `&` + LF.

Comment: @baddger964: That is little different from the original. `$` will match before a newline at the end of a string.

Comment: @baddger964 No, $ matches either the end of a string or before a newline at the end of a string